# I need to reset the nether

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I wanna reset the nether because 1.10 is a thing and I want the new magma blocks. Is it possible? I don't know if I even need to because I barely even go to the nether and I think I can load new chunks. Please tell me. I haven't even tried loading the new chunks. Oh, and I can't start a new world.

Answer (score 4):

The `DIM-1` folder of your world contains all of the data for the nether:

[image]

If you delete it, the nether will regenerate without affecting the end or the overworld.

---

If you go far enough out (past already-generated chunks), generating new chunks will also work to get magma blocks.

Comment: DIM1 or DIM-1? Please answer

Comment: @UltimateTemmieGamer `DIM-1` should be the nether, `DIM1` the end, and `region` the overworld.

Comment: `DIM-1` is Nether, you can open the folder then go to data then see `villages_nether.dat`: https://i.imgur.com/A5I8AKz.png